# extract price from different e-commerce site using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, e-commerce, web-scraping

I need to develop web app for extracting prices of books from different e-commerce sites like amazon,homeshop18 when user enters book name in the interface and displays all the information.

My questions are 
1)how to pass that query to amazon site search box and i can get only the pages relevant to the query instead of crawling the whole site.

2)What can be used to develop this application?BeautifulSoup or scrappy?API's are not available for all e-commerce sites to use it

am new to python.so any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Need more info. What site are you trying to scrape? What have you tried?

Comment: any book Shopping sites.I have used urllib module to fetch the html page source and don know how to produce further

Comment: You might want to consider using BeautifulSoup for your purposes. It helps parsing out HTML

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? there are tools already available to do that like https://www.agenty.com

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly use BeautifulSoup to parse web pages, but beware it's a bit slow if you have to parse pages massively. I know that [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is faster but a bit less coder-friendly.To guess the right parameters (either for an HTTP GET or POST) for getting the result page you want, you should proceed like this:

1. Switch on the firebug plugin for Firefox or the integrated inspector for Chrome
2. Go on the web page you're interested in, and do the search
3. Go into firebug/inspector to see the parameters of the HTTP request Firefox or Chrome sent to the website.
4. Reproduce the request in your python script. For example using urllib

There is another way to guess the right HTTP GET or POST parameters, it's to use a network analyzer like Wireshark. This is a more detailed approach but feels more like
finding a needle in a haystack once you used the tools in Firefox/Chrome.